# Secure authentication without SSL using Google App Engine?

Tags: security, google-app-engine, web-applications, authentication

I am working on a practice project for which I am trying to build a secure login system. Getting my own SSL certificate or a solution that needs a dedicated server is not an option. I was thinking about hosting the site on my domain but doing the authentication on my App Engine site. Is there any way of doing this securely without sending them over to the subdomain.example.com domain?

Answer (score 1):

App Engine doesn't currently support SSL on your own domain (and when it does, you'll still need to buy an SSL certificate, though that's not difficult). For a good review of why it's not really possible to secure sessions without SSL, see [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336678). If security is important to you, you'll need to serve the signed-in part of your site off yourapp.appspot.com for now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I've not understood your question, but have you considered OpenID?