# Yodlee API PKI, trying to encrypt data rsa/ecb/pkcs1padding using rails/ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yodlee

I'm creating an app using yodlee api, so far everything good, but right now, I'm having this block related to the PKI feature of yodlee. I'm not able to encrypt the data using "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" as they request, all  I found so far are java examples, anyone with a snippet of code, or a reference to make this possible on ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are referring to this [manual to integrate Yodlee API with PKI feature](https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/Yodlee_API_PKI_Feature).

Have a look into the ruby's **[OpenSSL](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html) classes**. Encryption using RSA is possible with the [`OpenSSL::PKey::RSA` class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey/RSA.html), see also this [intro doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html#module-OpenSSL-label-RSA+Encryption). Basically you have to load the public key returned from the API, and use the `public_encrypt` method to encrypt the data and hex-encode it in the end. The encryption [uses](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey/RSA.html#method-i-public_encrypt) the `PKCS1_PADDING` by default which is just what you want.

A complete example is available in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9891824/1544012).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if I can find any yodlee code sample? I'm already using the encryption but I'm still getting the decryption error.

Comment: I don't, sorry. If you have a concrete failing code, update the question or perhaps place a new one. In general, it should be an equivalent code to the Java code posted in the official manual.

Comment: Sorry if I mislead you, the output should be hex-encoded, not base64-encoded. I corrected the answer.