# Storing admin flag in $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I stored admin flags in the $_SESSION global variable. It's only modifiable server side, so I don't see a security issue.
This post here mentions that it's not safe: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/29719

Why is this?

```
Storing a admin flag in the session is only slightly better than adding a GET parameter admin=1. In other words this is no secure solution.
```

Comment: It is wrong, that answer is incorrect.

Comment: That's right, as soon as the storage for sessions is not compromised - it's safe to store a flag there.

Comment: Ah ok thank you, thought I had to rewrite my system.

Comment: A potential problem is [session hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking), if the server doesn't use http, one can intercept the session id, there are well documented cases of [session guessing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Insufficient_Session-ID_Length).

Comment: @CommuSoft I think you mean if the server doesn't use "https". Session hijacking is also not unique to the use of the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: true, but it is still unsafe. At that moment, the only chance is probably to use your own encryption system, and send thus the password each time (encrypted and time-depending). In other words emulating https.

Comment: @CommuSoft Never save passwords in a cookie, encrypted or not. [Hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) maybe, but salt it with other information. [Also, you can't emulate HTTPS over HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336678/login-without-https-how-to-secure).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: You can indeed not fully emulate https over http, because, well communication is open (the server directives thus). But indeed, using a hash, and better a changing one as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not correct. The security of this is fine.

Comment: Upvoted, just because this answer does not deserve to be downvoted (since it's technically correct).

Comment: @pawan **Question:** Why is storing admin flags in the Session considered insecure. **Answer:** It is not considered insecure.