# How to encrypt data client side and decrypt on another client side without SSL/TLS?

Tags: javascript, encryption

If I have Device A, Device B and Server, how can I achieve a secure transfer of information between the two devices?

I want to encrypt plain text on Device A, send it to the server, which will reroute it to Device B, which will decrypt the message. I haven't found many examples of this online. I was able to fiddle around with Node's `crypto`, but that is useless to me because it's server side. I'm using socket io and any initial connection that would send out any keys is a vulnerability. I am unable to use HTTPS or WSS.

What are my options here?

Comment: you may want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58360477/4215616). It explains a library named Libsodium and how to use it

Comment: Read some books of cryptography, comprehend the essence of TLS, then you can design your protocols with the help of current cryptographic algorithms.  For javascript, there's a very powerful tool named browserify, and the crypto functions have been implemented with pure JS, so you can communicate with Node.JS crypto module in a simple and straightforward manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unable to use HTTPS or WSS.
>
> What are my options here?

You have [no other options](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/) that will *actually* be secure. See also: [Login without HTTPS: How to Secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336678/login-without-https-how-to-secure)